# How can I replace these old ceiling tiles?

Tags: ceiling

I recently had a roof leak and some water got into my bedroom and the ceiling sagged a bit. It has appeared to dry out and we have cracks in the seams from the tiles apparently shrinking.
Upon closer review i notice the tiles appear to be like cardboard but I don't know where i would be able to find them. I am also wondering if they would have asbestos, in which case I wouldn't want to mess with it.
Any help is greatly appreciated and i have attached photos, and I think they are stick on tiles.[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to replace them or where to find them? The latter is a shopping question and therefore off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

This type of tile is composed of pressed fiber material. They have edges that engage each other in a tongue-and-groove arrangement. They're typically installed on 1x2 battens running under the continuous seams.

If you can find replacements, you can probably cut individual tiles out with a fresh utility knife. You'd then install the new tiles with construction adhesive. You'd need to support them for few hours, perhaps with temporary padded stilts.

You might find it easier to pull down the cove molding, overlay drywall, tape and paint, and reinstall the molding (or just tape the corners as normal).

Comment: Overlaying with drywall may be more weight than the battens will hold. The battens are not usually attached very well since yesteryears diy guys didnot have nail guns or powered screw drivers